# IIS server: how to dump IIS configuration into a single file

Tags: iis-7, configuration, web-server

How to export/import configuration of my IIS server into/from a single file? The reason is that I want to put the configuration under version control system to track changes made by admins.

Sultan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIS7's configuration data is stored in a bunch of XML config files in:

`%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\inetsrv\config`

There are still some settings that are registry bound and they can be found under:

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\InetStp\Components`

and

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server`

The approved way of backing up IIS7's configuration is by using the `APPCMD BACKUP` command. You can find out more about this command by running `APPCMD BACKUP /?` from an Administrator command prompt.

You can find out more about `APPCMD BACKUP` here:

> [Getting Started With APPCMD.EXE - Managing Backups](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe/#Managing)